# Should the sum of daily returns be close to monthly returns

Tags: returns

I am calculating value-weighted returns with monthly dividends reinvested and for some reason when I sum the daily returns some are a little bit off with monthly returns.

Is this normal?

Comment: well, are you using arithmetic returns or logarithmic returns? A basic fact from the properties of logarithm is that a total log return is the sum of daily returns, $$\log (X_n/X_0)=\sum_{k=1}^n \log(X_k/X_{k-1}).$$ This is not true for arithmetic, it is a slightly more complicated multiplicative formula.

Comment: You give very little detail of what you are doing. Where do your returns come from? Are you saying that using CRSP monthly vs daily returns you get different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should expect them to be different.  For example, consider -10% and +10%.  1.1*0.9 = 0.99 -> -1% return vs 0% if you use addition.